# Boxplot with pandas and groupby

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataset sample:

```
     0         1
0    0  0.040158
1    2  0.500642
2    0  0.005694
3    1  0.065052
4    0  0.034789
5    2  0.128495
6    1  0.088816
7    1  0.056725
8    0 -0.000193
9    2 -0.070252
10   2  0.138282
11   2  0.054638
12   2  0.039994
13   2  0.060659
14   0  0.038562
```

And need a box and whisker plot, grouped by column 0. I have the following:

```
plt.figure()
grouped = df.groupby(0)
grouped.boxplot(column=1)
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

But I end up with three subplots. How can place all three on one plot?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe you need to use groupby.

```
df2 = df.pivot(columns=df.columns[0], index=df.index)
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel()

>>> df2
0          0         1         2
0   0.040158       NaN       NaN
1        NaN       NaN  0.500642
2   0.005694       NaN       NaN
3        NaN  0.065052       NaN
4   0.034789       NaN       NaN
5        NaN       NaN  0.128495
6        NaN  0.088816       NaN
7        NaN  0.056725       NaN
8  -0.000193       NaN       NaN
9        NaN       NaN -0.070252
10       NaN       NaN  0.138282
11       NaN       NaN  0.054638
12       NaN       NaN  0.039994
13       NaN       NaN  0.060659
14  0.038562       NaN       NaN

df2.boxplot()
```

[image: boxplot]

Answer (score 29):

In 0.16.0 version of pandas, you could simply do this:

```
df.boxplot(by='0')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What is the scale of the y-axis?  It doesn't correspond to the data.

Comment: @Alexander Oh, that. I had changed the data on the local file. Have updated it now.

Comment: Here is the doc for the `by` cluase, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html. E.g., the box (whisker) plot can be grouped by more than one columns as well.